# Existence of a cofree functor (right adjoint)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Given is the forgetful functor: $U: Grp \rightarrow Set$. I've already seen that we can construct a left adjoint $F: Set \rightarrow Grp$ to this functor by introducing the free functor, which associates to any set $X \in Set$ the free group $F(X)$.

Now I want to check if there is a right adjoint to our forgetful functor, let's say it is the functor $R: Set \rightarrow Grp$. If we had a right adjoint, we'd have a bijection between hom-sets, namely $Hom_{Grp}(R(X), G) \simeq Hom_{Set}(X, U(G))$ for any set $X \in Set$ and $G \in Grp$. 
I guess there is no such a right adjoint to the forgetful functor $U$ but I don't know how to show it. Can anybody help me, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: The natural bijection you gave states that $R$ is a *left* adjoint of $U$. I assume this is a typo. At any rate, left adjoints preserve all colimits. Does $U$ preserve all colimits?

Comment: See the answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39490/dualizing-the-definition-of-a-free-group

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I understood why we cannot construct such a bijection if we consider any set $X$ with more than one element. +1 for both of you. @Derek, there is a typo! I apologize for it!